# PowerShell Password Vault

Tags: powershell

**Goal:**

I am building a Password Vault. I want to be able to restructure the table and change the names of the columns.

**Question:**

Is it possible to complete this task? And if yes how would I go about doing it?

**Example:**

```
UserName                                Resource                               Password                               Properties                            
--------                                --------                               --------                               ----------                            
username                                My App                                 password                               {[hidden, False], [applicationid, 0...
```

Is it possible to change the name of the column UserName,Resource and Password permanently for future entries?

```
function Get-SystemCreds{
  param(
    [switch]$AddCred,
    [switch]$Getcred,
    [switch]$RemoveCred
  )
  $vaultAssembly = [void][Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
  if($AddCred -eq $true){
    $vaultAssembly
    $ID= Read-Host 'Enter ID'
    $Password= Read-Host 'Password'
    $URL = Read-Host 'Enter URL'
    $vault=New-Object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault
    $cred=New-Object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential($ID, $Password, $URL)
    $vault.Add($cred)
  }
  if ($RemoveCred -eq $true){
    $vaultAssembly
    $ID = Read-Host 'Enter ID'
    $cred = Get-SystemCreds -Getcred |
    Where-Object {$_.UserName -eq $ID}
    $vault.Remove($cred)
  }
  if ($Getcred -eq $true){
    $vaultAssembly
    (new-object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault).RetrieveAll() | % { $_.RetrievePassword(); $_ }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this before somewhere. I will see if I can dig it up.

Comment: Thank you... any reason why I was downvoted? Let me know so I can fix my question...

Comment: Not sure, I didn't place the downvote. I would suggest that you add some of your vault's source code to show how it is structured currently, though.

Comment: I had an idea that I posted as an answer. I can't guarantee that it will work, but assuming that nothing strange is going on behind the scenes, it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#Formats username column, sets different title for column
$format= @{Expression={$_.UserName};Label="UserNameColumnNameHere"} #Add comma and add formatting for other columns after here
(new-object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault).RetrieveAll() | % { $_.RetrievePassword(); $_ } | format-table $format
```

Assuming the format of the table uses variables named the same as those shown in your picture, this should allow you to reformat your table's names by applying the format-table function to it.

Comment: I'm glad it turned out. I stripped it off of some old code which I used for an RSS feed reader, and I wasn't sure it would work quite that well here.