# Add bulk credentials in bulk to Password Vault

Tags: powershell

**Overview:**

I have created a vault that stores sensitive data, you can see my full sample code in this question:
[PowerShell Password Vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914442/powershell-password-vault)

**Goal:**

I am attempting to make a function that would add credentials in bulk. I am not looking for particular method. However, I did attempt to run a loop that would add creds on each new line. But, my logic is off somewhere, meaning that when I attempt to use the following code, it begins to add credentials in an erroneous manner- please see table below. I am very open to new ideas or suggestions as well.

**Exact Code:**

```
function Add-BulkCreds{
  param(
    [string]$ID,
    [string]$Key,
    [string]$URL
  )
  $vaultAssembly
  do{
    Write-Host 'AddCreds)' -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
    $x = Read-Host
    $first,$second,$third = $x -split '\s',3
    $vault = New-Object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault
    $cred = New-Object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential($second, $third, $first)
    $vault.Add($cred)
    }while($x)
}
```

**Example input:**

```
PS > Add-BulkCreds
AddCreds)test1c1 test1c2 test1c3
test2c1 test2c2 test2c3
test3c1 test3c2 test3c3
AddCreds)
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "3" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect.
Cannot create credential"
At C:\Users\getcred.ps1:83 char:13
+     $cred = New-Object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential($second,  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

**Output:**

```
     ID                                              Key                                                Endpoint                                      
--------                                           ------                                             -----------                                      
test1c3...                                         test1c1                                            test1c2
```

**Closer Look at ID column:**

```
PS > $credexample.id | Where-Object {$_.key -eq 'test1c1'}
test1c3
test2c1 test2c2 test2c3
test3c1 test3c2 test3c3
```

**Observation:**

As you can see the following part of my input was added to my ID column:

```
test1c3
test2c1 test2c2 test2c3
test3c1 test3c2 test3c3
```

Whereas....

**test1c1** was added to Key

**test1c2** was added to endpoint

**Question:**

Given my goal and overview, how can I create a simple, yet efficient function for adding credentials in bulk? And, does my logic work?

**Additionally:**

I am realizing that the original parameters aren't even needed since I am splitting the variable below with $x.

```
  param(
    [string]$ID,
    [string]$Key,
    [string]$URL
  )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "my logic is off somewhere"?

Comment: yes just a moment

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I added some code on what I meant about my logic being off, please let me know if I can clarify more.